# syntax error Call to undefined method mysqli::num_rows()

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to execute a function but I have these problem above
the code is

```
public function update_stats(){
    $mysqli = $this->connection();
    $activo ='1';
    $q1 = $mysqli->fetch_row($mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM usuarios WHERE activo = '$activo'"));
    $q2 = $mysqli->num_rows($mysqli->query('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM images'));
      $return['stats_miembros'] = $q1[0];
        $return['stats_images'] = $q2;
        $is_online = (time() - ($tsCore->settings['c_last_active'] * 60));
        $cueri = $mysqli->num_rows($mysqli->query('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `usuarios` WHERE `last_active` > \''.$is_online.'\''));
        $return['stats_online'] = $cueri;
        return $return;
}
```

I got the syntax error here:

```
$q1 = $mysqli->fetch_row($mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM usuarios WHERE activo = '$activo'"));
```

the `$mysqli = $this->connection();` function is:

```
private function connection(){
        return new mysqli($this->serv,$this->user,$this->pass,$this->base);
    }
```

Comment: Include the actual error you get.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::num_rows() in /home/*****/files/libs/ImageAccess.class.php on line 108

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
$q2 = $mysqli->query('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM images');
$numRows = $q2->num_rows;
```

and

```
$cueri = $mysqli->query('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `usuarios` WHERE `last_active` > \''.$is_online.'\'');
$numRowsNew = $cueri->num_rows;
```

[$mysqli_result->num_rows;](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)